# How to get the form elements in zend which contains the objct inside

Tags: php, zend-framework

While getting the form data in zend which contains the object.

If i print the `$form->getElements()` i get the following output:

```
array(38) {["0_0_1"] => object(Fields_Form_Element_ProfileType)#1153 (36) {
    ["helper"] => string(10) "formSelect"
    }
}
```

So now how can I get the `["helper"]` value ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Scenario is like this ["0_0_1"]->["some object"] the some object contains one more associative array ..now i want to get the ["someobject"] array values ..! I hope clearly explained my problem is ?

Comment: Safe way of doing this would be to get object from this array and call `get_class_methods($object)` to see if there is exposed method to get this helper. Only if there isn't you can try `$object->helper`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
foreach($form->getElements() as $element){
    var_dump($element->helper);
}
```